# Angular 9: custom component a valid mat-menu-item

Tags: javascript, angular

i want use a custom component into MatMenu as MatMenuItem:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-item',
  template: `<button>CustomItem</button>`
})
export class CustomItemComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <mat-menu>
    <button mat-menu-item>Foo</button>
    <my-custom-item mat-menu-item>Bar</my-custom-item>
  </mat-menu>
`,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

But it raise an exception:

> Template parse errors: More than one component matched on this
>   element. Make sure that only one component's selector can match a
>   given element. Conflicting components: MatMenuItem,CustomItemComponent
>   ("  Help
>   [ERROR ->] 
>   "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@3:4

see demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-hfdrwr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It is possible, make a custom component a valid mat-menu-item?

Comment: Can you show us your custom component's code?

Comment: it is into the question....

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your component to behave like a MatMenuItem, to achieve  that your custom component should extend from MatMenuItem.

[Here](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control) is the link to an example from Angular Material. It's for a different component type. But i'm mostly sure the steps you have to take is the same. Also check the [API of MatFormField](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api) used in the example and also [API of MatMenu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) to compare and create your custom component

Comment: I checked the links and they are working. Which was the one you couldn't open?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the comment on the initial post, that link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: here is a working example, however there are some highlighting issues left to figure out...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma4834389864331662-n2x2pi